# How to rename files - Remove the name and keep the number

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I need to rename a lot of files that contain a name and a badge number.

The files look like this: "John Doe 1234.txt" and I must rename it to 1234.txt
(new file must contain only badge number).
Also the badge number is not fixed, it could be contain 3-4 numbers.

Update:
The Filename contains 2-3 names separated with spaces.
E.g.: "John Doe 123.txt" or "John Junior Doe 1234.txt"

I was thinking to delete all letters and spaces from the name and only keep the numbers, but I don't know Powershell good enough.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does every single file have `FirstName <space> Last <space> #.txt` ? Like, there is no 3 name people or anything?

Comment: Is the length of the badge number always the same number of characters?

Comment: yes, there is space between names and badge number can be 3-4 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Filenames ***cannot*** contain special characters (`/\:*?"<>|`), but can contain chracters like `%` and `!` which can cause `cmd.exe` misinterception, so the code is not foolproof.</del> **THE CODE IS NOW FOOLPROOF.**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "dir=YOUR DIRECTORY HERE"
set "_output="
set "map=0123456789"

pushd "%dir%"

FOR %%a in (*.txt) do (
    SETLOCAL
    set "file=%%~na"
    1>temp.log echo(!file!
    for %%b in (temp.log) do set /A len=%%~zb-2
    del /F /Q temp.log
    for /L %%A in (0 1 !len!) do (
        for /F "delims=*~ eol=*" %%? in ("!file:~%%A,1!") do if "!map:%%?=!" NEQ "!map!" set "_output=!_output!%%?"
    )
    ren "!file!.txt" "!_output!.txt"
    ENDLOCAL
)
ENDLOCAL
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

---

<del>**Note**: can only handle up to 31 files, because of the `SETLOCAL`</del> **MY ASSUMPTION WAS WRONG.** It can handle infinite files, because of the paired `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL`.

Comment: "**Note**: can only handle up to 31 files, because of the SETLOCAL" --- Just another reason to abandon soon-to-be-obsolete batch & learn **PowerShell**!

Comment: @KeithMiller i was truly a idiot. the `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` are paired. It can handle infinite files!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all filenames are in format "First Last Number.txt

You can run:

```
pushd "C:\Temp\su\"
dir | ? { $_.Name -like "*.txt" } | 
% { Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName.split(' ')[2])$($_.Extension)" }
popd
```

Change the first line to match your path. (paste the entire snippet and press enter twice)

[image: Screenshot to show beginning filenames, the command, then the result.]

Comment: that works for first last number, but some are first middle last number :)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

Edit **$Source** as necessary.
"**-WhatIf**" parameter means posted code can be run to verify desired fies are found & NewName is correct. Remove the "-**WhatIf**" parameter to actually rename the files.

```
$Source = 'c:\path\to\files'
Get-CHildItem $SOurce *.txt -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Split(' ')[-1] } -whatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

presuming all the input files end with a space and then at least one digit, this looks like yet another way to do the job. it does NOT check for dupe numbers, tho. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- defines the source & destination dirs
  i am always twitchy about clobbering the original files, so this *copies them* instead of *renaming them*. if you want to do it directly, replace the `Copy-Item` with `Rename-Item`.
- creates some test dirs & files
  remove that whole region when you are ready to do things for real.
- defines the file type to grab
- gets the files that match the filter
- removes any files whose `.BaseName` props DO NOT end with a space and at least one digit
- splits the `.Basename` on the spaces and grabs the last item in the results
- adds the `.Extension` prop to the above
- builds the *new* full file name
- copies the OLD full file name to the NEW full file name
- the `-PassThru` on the `Copy-Item` line sends "created a file" info to the screen

the code ...

```
$SourceDir = "$env:TEMP\InFiles"
$DestDir = "$env:TEMP\OutFiles"

#region >>> make some test dirs & files
$SourceDir, $DestDir |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Null = mkdir -Path $_ -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
# the last file is not to be worked on - wrong pattern
@'
FName LName 1234.txt
Alfa Bravo Charlie 89.txt
First Middle Last 666.txt
Wiki Tiki Exotica Music.txt
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Null = New-Item -Path $SourceDir -Name $_ -ItemType 'File' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
#endregion >>> make some test files

$Filter = '*.txt'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filter -File |
    Where-Object {
        # filter out any basename that does NOT end with a space followed by at least one digit
        $_.BaseName -match ' \d{1,}$'
        } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # split on the spaces & take the last item from the resulting array
        $NewBaseName = $_.BaseName.Split(' ')[-1]
        $NewFileName = '{0}{1}' -f $NewBaseName, $_.Extension
        $FullNewFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $NewFileName
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $FullNewFileName -PassThru
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Batch File using the following method.

This will work regardless of how many letters and spaces are at the beginning.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "fPath=C:\test\my files\"

:: For each .txt file found in path %fPath% do....
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /B /ON "%fPath%*.txt"') do (
    echo Processing: %%a
    set "oName=%%a"
    set "fName=%%a"
    call :loop
)
echo Finished
endlocal
pause

:eof
exit /B



::=====================================================================
:: Check if the name is only numbers plus ".txt" on the end and if not, then remove the first character and check again.
:: If only numbers remaining, rename the original file. If no characters left then no match found and should go to next file.

:loop
if "!fName!"==".txt" exit /B
echo !fName!|findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]*\.txt$">nul
if !errorlevel! NEQ 0 set "fName=!fName:~1!" && goto :loop
ren "%fPath%%oName%" !fName!
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create an additional temp.log file to perform this task, nor worry about non-numeric characters in the file name...

If you are using **`U N I C O D E`** to do this, filtering in the loop **`for`**, and only get the numbers output from file name, where this can be done by:

```bat
cmd /u "echo\ string" | findstr regex
```

1) **`cmd /u`** will **`echo\string`** name character by character

```bat
cmd /u /c echo\John Doe 123.txt
```

2) **`findstr [0-9]`** will get to variable **`!_n!`** only number in loop **`%%~n`**

```bat
echo\John Doe 123.txt|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [0-9]
```

3) Use a variable **`!_n!`** to increment the **`%%~n`** character by joining only output numbers

```bat
set "_n=!_n!%%~n"
```

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "c:\path\to\your\files"
set "_where=%__APPDIR__%where.exe" 
set "_findstr=%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [0-9]"

for /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('!_where! .:"*.*"^|find/v "%~x0"')do (set "_str=%%~nS" && (
  for /f %%n in ('cmd/u/cecho\"!_str!"^|find/v " "^|!_findstr!')do set "_n=!_n!%%~n" )
   2>nul rename "%%~S" "!_n!%%~xS" && echo\"%%~S" ==^> .\!_n!%%~xS && set "_n=" <nul ) 

popd & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- For this file's path/name layout:

```bat
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Doe 123.txt
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Doe 1234.txt
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Junior Doe 00001.txt
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Junio Doe 154200 1 .txt
```

- The code results/output:

```bat
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Doe 123.txt ==> .\123.txt
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Doe 1234.txt ==> .\1234.txt
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Junior Doe 00001.txt ==> .\00001.txt
G:\SUPER_USER\Q1533871\John Junio Doe 154200 1 .txt ==> .\1542001.txt
```

- How to implement more tasks in the code...

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "c:\path\to\your\files"
set "_where=%__APPDIR__%where.exe" 
set "_findstr=%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [0-9]"

for /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('!_where! .:"*.*"^|find/v "%~x0"')do (set "_str=%%~nS" && (
  for /f %%n in ('cmd/u/cecho\"!_str!"^|find/v " "^|!_findstr!')do set "_n=!_n!%%~n" )
   2>nul rename "%%~S" "!_n!%%~xS" && echo\"%%~S" ==^> .\!_n!%%~xS && set "_n=" <nul

   rem ::  Aditionals taks commands enter here bellow here....

   ) 

popd & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

**For command line help, you can use `/?`:**

```bat
Pushd /?, Popd /?, Find /?, Findstr /?, Ren /?, For /?, Setlocal /?, Endlocal /?, Goto /?, Setlocal /?, Endlocal /?, if /?, timeout /?, ... /?
```

**On the internet, you can get more help on:**

- **[Popd](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)**
- **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
- **[Pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**
- **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**
- **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
- **[Timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)**
- **[Setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**
- **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**
- **[Ren / Rename](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**
- **[Goto :EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**
- **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)**
- **[If, Else If, Else, If Defined, Errorlevel ...](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

<sub>So sorry my limited English</sub>